# CSS: percentage and vh/vw together, weird result

Tags: html, css

I have a simple set of divs. I've been using vw/vh and percentages, but I stumbled across a weird problem I cannot understand. You can see the problem below:

[https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvQBgp#anon-login][1]

```css
.big{
width: 20vw;
height: 20vh;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border: 1px dotted black;
margin-top: 10vh;
}

.toprow {
background-color: cyan;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: space-between;
height: 20%;
}

.bottomrow {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
margin-top: 60%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
justify-content: space-between;
background-color: cyan;
height: 20%;
}


.left_top {
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
}

.right_top {
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
background-color: green;
}

.left_bottom {
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
background-color: orange;
}

.right_bottom {
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="tyyli2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="big">
<div class="toprow">
<div class="left_top">
</div>
<div class="right_top">
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottomrow">
<div class="right_bottom">
</div>
<div class="left_bottom">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used vh/vw for the "big div". I then reasoned that the correct way of defining the smaller divs would be percentages, because they are child elements inside the big div. This leads to the lower row not being inside the big div if/when the viewport size changes. The html structure is correct. As a comparison if I define *all* units in vh/vw, it works. To my knowledge that's not how it should be, because the smaller divs are inside the big div ans thus should be defined as percentage of the big div, right? Why do the percentages "fail" in this setting?

Could you please shed some light on this matter :) Thanks! Btw, this might look like a home works (as it's so ridiculous), but it is not. I'm learning css/html just for fun, and this was a challenge I made up in my feeble mind :D

Answer (score 1):

You probably think that you are adding 20% plus 60% plus 20% here and should get a 100% as result - but those 60% are not calculated on the same base value as those 20% to begin with.

A percentage value for margin always is in reference to the *width* of the containing block - even for margin-top and -bottom.

`height:20%` means 20% of the height of the parent - but `margin-top:60%` means 60% of the *width* of the containing block.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that :) If/when the margin-top cannot be used, what would be the way to "push" the bottomrow all the way to the bottom of the big div? Any other way than to use vw/vh instead of %?

Comment: Then you probably better go flexbox with the parent container already, so that you can align the items inside to the top and bottom, resp. use space-between.